# How can i compare Array.find with iterators like for foreach etc..?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

I regularly use `for` loop , `forEach` loop , `Array.map` etc for iterating arrays. i came to know that we can also use `Array.find` for looping array and it can also return the values matched in the array based on condition:

I have iterated array of objects using `Array.find()` and `for` loop as follows

**Using Array.find:**

```
[{
    name: "John"
}, {
    name: "Cannady"
}, {
    name: "Sherlock"
}].find(function(oArrayObject) {
    console.log(oArrayObject)   
});
```

output on console:

```
{name: "John"}
{name: "Cannady"}
{name: "Sherlock"}
```

**Using for loop:**

```
    var aNames=[{
           name: "John"
        }, {
            name: "Cannady"
        }, {
            name: "Sherlock"
        }]

for(var i=-0;i<aNames.length;i++){
console.log(aNames[i]);
}
```

output on console:

```
{name: "John"}
{name: "Cannady"}
{name: "Sherlock"}
```

Both codes did the same thing.

What is the advantage of Array.find() over for loop??

Which one gives the better performance ??

Please explain me the difference between array.find and other iterators in terms of performance , usage , internal functionality etc...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [For-each over an array in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: You should also try `forEach`, `every`, `some`, `map`, ... but maybe also read the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) is used to, well, find an item in the array that matches a predicate, and return it. When `Array.find` returns, the loop ends. Performance wise, you don't have to iterate the whole array, if the item you seek is not the last.

```js
var result = [{
    name: "John"
}, {
    name: "Cannady"
}, {
    name: "Sherlock"
}].find(function(o) {
    return o.name.startsWith('Ca');
});

console.log(result);
```

There are many methods to iterate arrays ([see array in mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)), such as:
`forEach`, `map`, `filter`, `reduce`, `reduceRight`, `some`, `every`, `find`, and `findIntex`.

Except for `Array#forEach`, most of them provide additional functionality beyond the iteration itself.

Answer (score 3):

> The find() method returns a value of the first element in the array
>   that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise undefined is
>   returned.

`find` function use a callback function, for example:

```
function isBigEnough(element) {
   return element >= 15;
}
[12, 5, 8, 130, 44].find(isBigEnough);
```

The find method executes the callback function once for each element present in the array until it finds one where callback returns a true value. If such an element is found, find immediately returns the value of that element.

The performance of `find` function varies, can be `O(1)`,or `O(n)` or less,in contrast to the `forEach` and `for` ,where complexity is **always** `O(n)` because you have to iterate all the `array`.

Comment: Array.prototype.some and Array.prototype.find are buddies in a way, ` some`  is a carefree type of person tho

Answer (score 1):

Using for/forEach for iteration is when you need to touch or check every object in the collection.  The find method is when you know what you're looking for and just want a quick search through the collection to see if it's there.